# How to make function false in jquery, if bootstrap modal is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 modal form with login button, When i open modal and press enter then `loginVelidation()` call it is working fine but when i hide bootstrap modal this function `loginVelidation()` is working. But i don't want this function `loginVelidation()` when modal is hide.

How can i do that?

This is my code:-

```js
$(function(){

    $('#loginModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        $(document).on('keypress', function(e){
            if(e.which == 13){
                loginVelidation();
            }
        });
    });

    $('#loginModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    });
});


function loginVelidation(){
    alert('test');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="loginModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="loginBtn" onclick="loginVelidation();">Login</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer will be appreciated!

Comment: Thats probably because you have 'keypress' event listening to document. Try something like $('#loginModal').on('keypress', function(e){} , you won't need to check visibility of modal then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the modal is visible with jQuery like this. Keep in mind that 'on.shown.modal' is the event that is triggered. And does not check the current state of the modal.

```js
$(function(){
        $(document).on('keypress', function(e){
            if(e.which == 13){
              if ($('#loginModal').is(':visible')) {
                loginVelidation();
              }
            }
});
});



function loginVelidation(){
    alert('test');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="loginModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="loginBtn" onclick="loginVelidation();">Login</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the event listener inside the `show.bs.modal` event. Inside the `keypress` event check if the modal is `visible` & use `===` instead of double `==`

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if ($('#loginModal').is(':visible')) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        loginVelidation();
      }
    }
  });
})

function loginVelidation() {
  alert('test');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="loginModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="loginBtn" onclick="loginVelidation();">Login</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check the whether the modal is hidden or visible then do the validation

```js
$(function(){

    $('#loginModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        $(document).on('keypress', function(e){
            if(e.which == 13 && ($("#loginModal").data('bs.modal') || {})._isShown    ){
                loginVelidation();
            }
        });
    });

    $('#loginModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    });
});


function loginVelidation(){
    alert('test');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="loginModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="loginBtn" onclick="loginVelidation();">Login</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I hope this will help you.